# Why does my quicksort is not working correctly?

Tags: c++, quicksort

I what to make a simple quicksort based on iterators. Every time I run it either sorts wrong or gives me strange numbers which are not a part of the collection. What can be fixed?

```cpp
template <typename I, typename C>
void quickSort(I begin, I end, C cmp) {
    if (begin >= end) throw new exception_incorrectSelection;
    I i = begin, j = end, pivot = i + (j - i) / 2;
    while (i <= j) {
        while (cmp(*i, *pivot)) ++i;
        while (cmp(*pivot, *j)) --j;
        if (i <= j) {
            std::iter_swap(i, j);
            ++i;
            --j;
        }
    }
    if (j > begin) {
        quickSort(begin, j, cmp);
    }
    if (i < end) {
        quickSort(i, end, cmp);
    }
}
```

On input `1 80 12 23 14 69 69 42 19 3 50 24 19 71 53 52 46 63 79` it gives me the output `80 79 69 54 69 42 23 19 14 12 71 63 53 52 50 46 24 19 3 1` (if I give second parameter as end() - 1)

Comment: Have you stepped through your code line-by-line while it was executing using a debugger?

Comment: My advice is find a much smaller example that fails then use your debugger to step through the code line by line. Also did the compiler issue any warnings on your code?

Comment: Yes.  If you can't sort 3, 4, or 5 items, it makes no sense to try and sort 20.  Make the code work for the smaller amount of items.

Comment: When `begin >= end` just `return;`. Don't use exceptions for flow control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour of debugging I changed pivot to `c++ T pivot = *(i + (j - i) / 2);` and now it works. Thanks everyone for support!

Comment: The reason for the prior problem is that the pivot and/or elements equal to the pivot may get swapped to just about anywhere during a partition step (since this is using Hoare partition method), so the pivot needs to be a value, not an iterator.